# Passing parameters to conditional statements in HTML5

Tags: html5, custom-variables

I want a link to say **Broadcast (Online)** when someone is online, and **Broadcast (Offline)** when someone isn't.

I know I can write an **if** statement, but how do I pass the parameter that someone is online to the website?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **web development** which is off-topic at Pro Webmasters. Web development questions may be asked at [so] but be sure to read their [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help) before posting to ensure your question meets their guidelines. In its current form, this question does *not* meet their guidelines.